# How do I remove surrounding spaces from each value in multidimensional array recursively

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

Each string value within my `$arr` array contains 2 preceeding white spaces. I would like to remove these spaces using the `trim()` method. Furthermore, I would like to do the same for any arrays within the `$arr` array assuming an infinite number of arrays within arrays. I attempted to do this recursively with no success.

Although there might be a built in php method to do this for me, I am learning, and would like to know why this code block doesn't work as well as what altercation can be made to fix it.

```
$arr = array("  one", "  two", array("  three"));

function trimAll(&$array) {
  foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(gettype($value) !== "array") {
        $array[$key] = trim($value);
    } else {
        trimAll($value);
    }
  }
}

trimAll($arr);

echo $arr[0];//"one" (worked)
echo $arr[1];//"two" (worked)
echo $arr[2][0];// "  three"(didn't work)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best/simplest function to call in this case is: `array_walk_recursive()`.  There is no need to reinvent a function that php has already designed for just this purpose.  It only visits "leaf nodes" so you don't need to check if it is processing an array-type element.

You merely need to modify the elements by reference (using `&` in the anonymous function parameter).  I'll demo `ltrim()` since your input strings only have leading spaces, but you can use `trim()` to handle spaces on both sides of the string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/h2ZLc)) ([PHP7.4 and higher version](https://3v4l.org/ZCIrM))

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $arr,
    function(&$v) {
        $v = ltrim($v);
    }
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'one',
  1 => 'two',
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'three',
  ),
)
```

---

As for your custom function, it could be written like this to provide a successful result:

```
function trimAll(&$array) {     // modify the original input array by reference
    foreach ($array as &$value) {  // modify each value by reference
        if (!is_array($value)) {      // if it is not an array
            $value = trim($value);    // trim the string
        } else {
            trimAll($value);        // recurse
        }
    }
}

trimAll($arr);                  // modify the array (no return value from function call)
var_export($arr);               // print the array
```

You see, the reason your subarray element is not being affected is because there is no assignment occuring between `$value` and `trimAll($value)`.  The way you have set up `trimAll`, it does not return a value.  So, even if you used:

```
} else {
    $array[$key] = trimAll($value);
}
```

You would find that `$array[$key]` would be replaced by `NULL`.  The solution is to make `$value` modifiable by reference by using `&$value` in the foreach loop.

---

And as if this answer wasn't long enough already, here is a way to reconfigure your function so that it returns the modified array instead of modifying the input array with no return.

```
function trimAll($array){            // input array is not modifiable
    foreach ($array as &$value) {      // $value IS modifiable
        if (is_array($value)) {        // if an array...
            $value = trimAll($value);  // assign recursion result to $value
        } else {                       // not an array...
            $value = trim($value);     // trim the string
        }
    }
    return $array;                   // return the new trimmed array
}
var_export(trimAll($arr));           // now trimAll() can be directly printed to screen
```

or if you wish to avoid modifying by reference entirely:

```
function trimAll($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $array[$key] = trimAll($value);
        } else {
            $array[$key] = trim($value);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
var_export(trimAll($arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a built-in PHP function which solves your problem. It is [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

But in your situation, you might need to do something like this:

#### Solution 1:

```
$input = array("  one", "  two", array("  three"));

function removeSpaces($object)
{
    if (is_array($object)) {
        $object = array_map('trim', $object);
    } else {
        $object = trim($object);
    }

    return $object;
}


$output = array_map('removeSpaces', $input);
```

#### Solution 2:

```
$input = array("  one", "  two", array("  three"));

function array_map_recursive(callable $func, array $array) {
    return filter_var($array, \FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => $func]);
}

$output = array_map_recursive('trim', $input);
```

Cheers.

Comment: Solution 1 is only suitable for input arrays with a maximum of 2 levels.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/76f9af45b01eedf1354a6b7be1d76d4702172e55  Yes, the OP's sample input is only 2 levels, but recursive solutions on this page should be able to process an unlimited number of levels.  Solution 2 satisfies the brief.

Answer (score 0):

Simple method,

```
$arr = array("  one", "  two", array("  three"));

function trimAll(&$array) {
  foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if(gettype($value) !== "array") {
        $array[$key] = trim($value);
    } else {
        $array[$key] = trimAll($value);
    }
  }
  return $array;
}

trimAll($arr);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.